# Create custom API to get the data from application layer to kerel layer in android (AOSP)

Tags: android, api, android-source

I working AOSP 11 source code.

Trying to understand the all layers of android.
How to create API to get data from application layer to kernel layer.

Application layer <=> Android framework <==> JNI <==> HAL <==> device drivers <==> kernel

Can you please share me any ref documents, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a good link if you wanted to create your own API's and communicate between Application layer to kernel layer. This example was carried out for Android 12.
[Go through the blog one by one and try to do the configurations accordingly](https://www.codeinsideout.com/blog/android/hal/aidl/#implement-hal-service)